# IOS In-App purchase - Subscription not gets using getSubscriptions() function In react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, subscription

How to get subscriptions from App store connect. I make subscription group and in that add subscriptions. but using skus can not get subscriptions in my code please provide solution for it.

I make subscription like displays in below Images.

1. account opens and make subscription group.
   [image]
2. now, i go to make a subscriptions. added all details and added productId
   [image]

3. now I write this code and add code for getSubscriptions(), but it is not working.

```
 const {
        connected,
        subscriptions, //returns subscriptions for this app.
        getSubscriptions, //Gets available subsctiptions for this app.
        currentPurchase, //current purchase for the tranasction
        finishTransaction,
        purchaseHistory, //return the purchase history of the user on the device (sandbox user in dev)
        getPurchaseHistory, //gets users purchase history
    } = useIAP();

    const subSkus = [
        'brandingSubs3999',
        ];
    
        //   get subscription
    const handleGetSubscriptions = async () => {
        try {
            if (connected) {
                console.log("subskus calling...")
                const subs = await getSubscriptions({ skus: subSkus });
                
                console.log("subs", subs, "subscriptions:", subscriptions);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("error in handle get subscription:", error)
        }
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        handleGetSubscriptions();
    }, []);
```

Logs:

```
subs undefined subscriptions: []
```

**I Do only this above things, but it is not working, please provide me solution how to get all subscription?**

Not getting any errors, but not getting any data of subscriptions, getting Only blank array. like any product id is not working.

Answer (score 0):

1. Problem fetching subscription SKU's via getSubscription method in useIAP hook : https://github.com/dooboolab-community/react-native-iap/issues/1601
2. The problem is that you're attempting to use the getSubscriptions function directly, but it isn't an independent function. It is part of the react-native-iap library. Import the useIAP hook from the library and use it to call the getSubscriptions function.

   ```
   import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
   import { useIAP } from 'react-native-iap';

   const App = () => {
     const { connected, getSubscriptions } = useIAP();
     const [subscriptions, setSubscriptions] = useState([]);

     const subSkus = ['brandingSubs3999'];

     const handleGetSubscriptions = async () => {
       try {
        if (connected) {
         const subs = await getSubscriptions({ skus: subSkus });
         setSubscriptions(subs);
       }
     } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error in handleGetSubscriptions:', error);
    }
   };

   useEffect(() => {
    handleGetSubscriptions();
   }, [connected]);

   return (
     // Your app's UI goes here
   );
   };

   export default App;
   ```
3. Implement React Native in-app purchases for Android apps : https://blog.logrocket.com/implement-react-native-in-app-purchases-android-apps/
4. In-App Purchase in React Native: A Comprehensive Guide : https://medium.com/@greennolgaa/in-app-purchase-in-react-native-a-comprehensive-guide-777d608fd25
5. Best React Native in-app subscription libraries : https://blog.logrocket.com/best-react-native-in-app-subscription-libraries/

Comment: Hello, I am already using useIap hook... but getting empty array from this function ... 

const {
        connected,
        getSubscriptions, //Gets available subsctiptions for this app.
        currentPurchase, //current purchase for the tranasction
        finishTransaction,
        purchaseHistory, //return the purchase history of the user on the device (sandbox user in dev)
        getPurchaseHistory, //gets users purchase history
    } = useIAP();

Comment: now check i changed in useState to manage subscription state and useEffect will re-run handleGetSubscriptions whenever the connected state changes

Comment: Already i got connected status true, so i think not need to add function in useEffect, but still i add your code ... getting same log, 'got subscriptions: undefined'.
may be it is issue of product id or app store connect related, no need to change in code my code is perfect may be!!!

please give me your any contact details, email, telegram or other. it is very important task please!!!

Comment: hello pratik do you have any solution?